# Prevent short-circut using 3.5mm and mp3 player to 12v

Tags: dc, short-circuit

I'm trying to wire an aux port into my am/fm car stereo. I don't have a pin out or board layout. I take the 3.5 mm wire, and hook it up to a cheap mp3 player. I attach the ground end of the 3.5 wire and then probe the left or right channel to arbitrary pins on the board to see which one will take it as an input and play the audio.

The problem comes, when I jump to the wrong pin. I imagine I hit the 12v power. I blew my mp3 player. Is there a way I can prevent the mp3 from getting burned out? A fuse might work, but I'm not sure what amp would be. What about a diode, that way the 12v can't feed back into the mp3 player.

Comment: Where does 12 V come into the picture?

Comment: The 12v is power supply from the car to the radio.

Comment: They make pretty cheap FM transmitters for just this application, something like [this one from Target](https://www.target.com/p/just-wireless-174-fm-transmitter-and-car-charger-black/-/A-15133554?sid=1483S&ref=tgt_adv_XS000000&AFID=google_pla_df&CPNG=PLA_Electronics+Shopping_Local&adgroup=SC_Electronics&LID=700000001170770pgs&network=g&device=c&location=9019054&gclid=Cj0KCQjwp_DPBRCZARIsAGOZYBQc_HQcipSkJ-0rlYugdzf7tvAUHkgmsPRAa6PuEkKyIZISIEcACLQaAurdEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds), might be cheaper than possibly blowing your stereo or MP3 player...

Comment: A smallish resistor 100 ohm .. 1 kohm should protect the MP3 player from shorting.  You should also add some clamping (zener) diodes (on the player side of the resistor) to protect it from over-voltage.

Comment: Sure, but how does that come anywhere near you 3.5 mm jack?

Comment: @winny, I'm randomly probing and I might hit a 12v line.

Comment: @RonBeyer I hate fm transmitters, and $20 is a lot more expensive than the free 3.5mm wire I have and the transmitter also takes up my cigarette lighter port that I need to charge my phone.

Comment: Why? And why would the 12 V be exposed in the first place? XY problem!

Comment: @winny  I can use a multimeter and find ground and 12v all over the board. I can't explain why it's exposed, but it is.

Comment: @OskarSkog thanks, that sounds like what I wanted.

Comment: Does the radio have an old-fashioned potentiometer volume control?

Comment: @Transistor yeah, It's a turning style volume control, so I'm pretty sure it's a potentiometer. What does that have to do with anything?

Answer (score 3):

> Me: Does the radio have an old-fashioned potentiometer volume control?
>
> You: It's a turning style volume control, so I'm pretty sure it's a potentiometer. What does that have to do with anything?

That's usually placed between the pre-amplifier and the power amplifier. Therefore it's a good place to inject an external audio signal.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFGxUO.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. (a) The original circuit. (b) Suggested modification.*

- The audio can be injected at R9 and R10 at the top of the volume control.
- R7 and R8 are required so that when the pre-amplifier output is zero-volts that they don't short out the signal injected at R9 and R10. Effectively R7 and 9 form a summing / averaging circuit for the PRE and TIP signal.
- You'll have to cut the trace between PRE and the top of the pot to insert the resistor. (You could try the mod without R7 and 8 first and see if its acceptable.)
- Measure the pot resistance and start with R7 - 10 with the same values as the pot. You will find that you need the volume control higher than before after this modification if R7 and 8 are added.
- Adjust R9 and 10 to get the same volume level from your AUX as from your radio so that you don't blow your ears when switching from one to the other.

Comment: This is great stuff. How do I know what value to use for the new resistors?

Comment: I told you in the answer.

Comment: if you have a 3.5mm socket with switched tip and ring contacts you can use the switches to disconnect the pre-amplifier from the potentiometers.

Comment: @jarchuleta the resistance is typically written on the pot eg: 50KA means 50 kilo ohms,  so start with something close like 47 kiloohms.